# Sequence Converging to Another Sequence, Can We Apply DCT?

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose I have integrable function sequences $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$ and we know that point wisely, $f_n(x)\to g_n(x)$, to be more specific, $\forall x$ and $\forall \epsilon>0$, $\exists N$ such that $\forall n>N$, we have

$$|f_n(x)-g_n(x)|<\epsilon.$$

and that both $f_n(x)$ and $g_n(x)$ are dominated by some integrable function $h(x)$. Can we conclude via some version of DCT that

$$\int f_n(x)dx \to \int g_n(x)dx?$$

Comment: Can you clarify the meaning of "$f_n(x)\to g_n(x)$"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli Thanks for the comment. I have edited the text and added some clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each $n$, $$\left\lvert\int f_n-\int g_n\right\rvert\le\int\lvert f_n-g_n\lvert$$

As you've written, $\lvert f_n-g_n\rvert\to 0$ pointwise and it is dominated by $\lvert h_f\rvert+\lvert h_g\rvert$. Therefore the RHS converges to zero and $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(\int f_n-\int g_n\right)=0$$

regardless of even either (and thus both) of the integrals actually converging.

Comment: Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for. Out of curiosity, if $|f_n-g_n|\to 0$ not point-wise, but in probability, do we have some version of DCT to use? Or it simply that the conclusion not necessarily hold anymore.

Comment: If you replace "$f_n-g_n\to 0$ pointwise" with "$f_n-g_n\to 0$ in measure" all the passages hold verbatim. @Bayesric